# Poco as static library with dynamic runtime requires import library of DLL?

Tags: windows, static-linking, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use Poco as a static library with dynamic runtime inside my project. I've downloaded the complete sources of Poco 1.7.3 and used the `buildwin.bat` script to compile the libraries using my self-compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2h shared library (i.e. adjusted the path in `buildwin.bat`).

Producing `PocoXYZmd.lib` via `buildwin.bat 140 build static_md debug Win32 nosamples notests msbuild` works fine.

However, when I try to link against `PocoXYZmd.lib` inside my own project, the linker searches for `PocoXYZ.lib`, the import library for `PocoXYZ.dll`.

Building Poco with `shared` and providing the `PocoXYZ.lib` import libraries within the linker search path, I'm getting errors on Poco symbols being already defined (obviously).

Am I missing something crucial or is it a bug in Poco's build script?

---

I've configured Poco to ONLY build the following components: Foundation, XML, JSON, Util, Net, Crypto, NetSSL_OpenSSL.

In addition, I had to adjust the v140 `vcxproj`-files of Crypto and NetSSL_OpenSSL to link to `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib` (the import libraries for the OpenSSL DLLs) instead of `libeay32md.lib` and `ssleay32md.lib` (no idea where these could come from based on the OpenSSL 1.0.2h build scripts).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 on Windows 7, doing everything within the 32bit Visual Studio Developer Prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the Poco documentation, I finally found the solution:

When using Poco statically on Windows, one must specify `POCO_STATIC` when compiling the library/application using Poco, otherwise several `#pragma comment` directives in Poco's headers will silently force linking to the DLL version of Poco.

http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-WindowsPlatformNotes.html

Thanks, RTFM.